# Download crypted (XOR) content

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have one online TXT file encrypted with XOR. And I'm using Indy HTTP to read this file. When I do this:

```
Buff.Text:= HTTP.Get('http://www.blabla.com/xor.txt');
```

the content in Buff is corrupted and I can't decrypt it correctly. How to solve this? Below I'll paste the function I'm using to XOR the txt file:

```
function TForm1.XorStr(Input: AnsiString; Seed: integer): AnsiString;
var
i : integer;
Output : AnsiString;
begin
    Output := '';
    for i := 1 to Length(Input) do
        Output := Output + AnsiChar(Ord(Input[i]) XOR (Seed));
    Result:= Output;
end;
```

Hope someone can helps me out. Thank you guys!

Comment: Is this the same algorithm that was used to encrypt the file?  It appears that you're using the same `seed` for every byte in the string, which isn't really all that useful for cryptography.

Comment: Yes is the same algorithm. I'm not worried about doing such a good cryptography algorithm. Only worried about download the content without corrupting it.

Comment: is the length of your downloaded file the same as the original?  I'm thinking that maybe http is truncating the data on you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are downloading the data using the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `UnicodeString`.  That version will decode the raw data to Unicode, based on the charset that is specified (or missing) in the server's `Content-Type` response header.  For what you are attempting to do, that corrupts your data.  You need to use the other overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that fills a `TStream` with the raw data instead, then you can decode it, eg:

```
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
  Output: AnsiString;
begin
  ...
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    HTTP.Get('http://www.blabla.com/xor.txt', Strm);
    Output := XorStr(Strm.Memory, Strm.Size, Seed);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;

function TForm1.XorStr(Input: Pointer; InputSize: NativeInt; Seed: Integer): AnsiString;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(Input), InputSize);
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
    Result[i] := AnsiChar(Ord(Result[i]) XOR Seed);
end;
```